# Get Date of days of a week given year, month and week number (relative to month) in Javascript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime, momentjs

I want a **function `getDaysOfWeekDates` that if I pass as parameters a year, a month (between 0 and 11) and a week of each month (usually each month has 4-5 weeks), it gives me a list of dates that contains each day of that week**. For example:

```ts
function getDaysOfWeekDates(year: number, month: number, weekNumber: number): Array<Date> {
     //...
}
```

```ts
const days: Date[] = getDaysOfWeekDates(2020, 0, 2) // Second week of January 2020
console.log(days);

/**
 * 2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-11T00:00:00.000Z
 * 2020-01-12T00:00:00.000Z
 */
```

I was able to build a function `getDaysOfWeekDates2` that works like this, but using a year and a week as parameter (week relative to year, each year has 52-53 weeks):

```ts
function getDaysOfWeekDates2(year: number, weekNumber: number) {
    const [ startDate ] =  getDateRangeOfWeek(year, weekNumber);

    return new Array(7).fill(null).map((e, index) => {
      
      return new Date(
        startDate.getFullYear(), 
        startDate.getMonth(), 
        startDate.getDate() + index
      );
    });
}
```

```ts
function getDateRangeOfWeek(year: number, weekNumber: number){
    
    const date = new Date(String(year));

    const numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday = date.getDay() - 1;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 * (weekNumber - getWeekNumber(date))));

    const rangeIsFrom =  new Date(date.getFullYear() + "-" +(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 6);
    const rangeIsTo = new Date(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + + date.getDate());
    
    return [rangeIsFrom, rangeIsTo];
};
```

```ts
function getWeekNumber(date: Date): number {
    const dateCopy = new Date(date.getTime());

    dateCopy.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Thursday in current week decides the year.
    dateCopy.setDate(dateCopy.getDate() + 3 - (dateCopy.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    // January 4 is always in week 1.
    const week1 = new Date(dateCopy.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
    return 1 + Math.round(((dateCopy.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
  }
```

**Any idea any idea how to modify `getDaysOfWeekDates?` to get the desired function `getDaysOfWeekDates`?** Or just **build it from scratch using some library**?

Comment: How do you define the first week of a month? E.g. what is the first day of the week, and how do you identify the first day of the first week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Monday as the first day of the week, and the first week of a month is the one with the first Thursday, then you can use a similar algorithm to the year week number function.

So get the start of the required week, then just loop 7 times to get each day. E.g.

```js
/* Return first day of specified week of month of year
**
** @param {number|string} year - year for required week
** @param {number|string} month - month for required week
**         Month is calendar month number, 1 = Jan, 2 = Feb, etc.
** @param {number|string} week - week of month
**         First week of month is the one with the first Thursday
** @returns {Date} date for Monday at start of required week
*/
function getMonthWeek(year, month, week) {
  // Set date to 4th of month
  let d = new Date(year, month - 1, 4);
  // Get day number, set Sunday to 7
  let day = d.getDay() || 7;
  // Set to prior Monday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - day + 1);
  // Set to required week
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7 * (week - 1));
  return d;
}

// Return array of dates for specified week of month of year
function getWeekDates(year, month, week) {
  let d = getMonthWeek(year, month, week);
  for (var i=0, arr=[]; i<7; i++) {

    // Array of date strings
    arr.push(d.toDateString());

    // For array of Date objects, replace above with
    // arr.push(new Date(d));

    // Increment date
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

// Week dates for week 1 of Jan 2020 - week starts in prior year
console.log(getWeekDates(2020, 1, 1));
// Week dates for week 5 of Jan 2020 - 5 week month
console.log(getWeekDates(2020, 1, 5));
// Week dates for week 1 of Oct 2020 - 1st is a Thursday
console.log(getWeekDates(2020, 10, 1));
// Week dates for week 1 of Nov 2020 - 1st is a Sunday
console.log(getWeekDates(2020, 11, 1));
```

It's not clear whether you want an array of Date objects or strings, so a Date object version is included in comments.